# no consigo como que mi codigo divida las unidades decenas y centenas con el punto en js

Tags: javascript, html

me pasa que tengo un codigo que me genera una tabla, haciendo conversion, la cosa es que me hace el calculo y lo devuelve sin los puntos, no se que hacer ni que implementar para que lo divida bien las unidades, decenas y sentenas, la verdad es que soy nuevo y este es un mini proyecto pero de aqui no e podido avanzar, les dejo el codigo pd: apenas estoy aprendiendo

me gustaria que me explicaran que puedo implementar y como y donde se hace, e buscado por la web e encontrado respuestas pero solo dicen que se podria hacer, no como se implementaria

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="es">
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>tabla</title>

     <script>

     function calcular_valores() {

     var tasa = document.getElementById("tasa").value;

     var val1 = 20.000;
     var val2 = 30.000;
     var val3 = 40.000;
     var val4 = 50.000;
     var val5 = 60.000;
     var val6 = 70.000;
     var val7 = 80.000;
     var val8 = 90.000;
     var val9 = 100.000;


    var val1convertido = val1 / tasa;
    var val2convertido = val2 / tasa;
    var val3convertido = val3 / tasa;
    var val4convertido = val4 / tasa;
    var val5convertido = val5 / tasa;
    var val6convertido = val6 / tasa;
    var val7convertido = val7 / tasa;
    var val8convertido = val8 / tasa;
    var val9convertido = val9 / tasa;    

    document.getElementById("1der").innerHTML = val1convertido.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("2der").innerHTML = val2convertido.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("3der").innerHTML = val3convertido.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("4der").innerHTML = val4convertido.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("5der").innerHTML = val5convertido.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("6der").innerHTML = val6convertido.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("7der").innerHTML = val7convertido.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("8der").innerHTML = val8convertido.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("9der").innerHTML = val9convertido.toFixed(3);

     }

   
      function addCommas(nStr)
      {
     nStr += '';
     x = nStr.split('.');
     x1 = x[0];
     x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
     var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
     while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return  x1 + x2
    }
    </script>

    </head>
   <body>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p>
      Introduce tasa de conversion: <input type="number" id="tasa" value="">       
    </p>
  </td>
  <td>
      <button onclick="calcular_valores()">Calcular</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong> Pesos</strong></td>
  <td>Valor En bolivares</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>
      <label id="1izq">20.000</label>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <label id="1der">0.000</label>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>
      <label id="2izq">30.000</label>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <label id="2der">0.000</label>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="3izq">40.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="3der">0.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="4izq">50.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="4der">0.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="5izq">60.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="5der">0.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="6izq">70.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="6der">0.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="7izq">80.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="7der">0.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="8izq">90.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="8der">0.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="9izq">100.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label id="9der">0.000</label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Todo ese codigo deberias intentarlo simplicar, utilizando multiples "for"...

Comment: Con un solo for bastaría, no hace falta múltiples @DiegoAndrés

Answer (score 1):

```
function calcular_valores() {

        var tasa = document.querySelector("#tasa").value;
        if (!tasa){tasa = 0}
            else{}

        for(var i = 2; i <= 10; i++){
            var val     = i*10000;
            var conv    = val/tasa;

            document.getElementById(i-1+"der").innerHTML = conv.toFixed(2);
        }
     }
```

Esa función está mas optimizada, con un simple bucle for te ahorras todas esas variables que lo único que hacen es cargar el código innecesariamente.

Bien, vamos paso por paso:

1. No se donde llamabas a la función addCommas, ni cual era el valor pasado por lla (nStr), así que la quité.
2. Cogemos el valor de #tasa, lo metemos en la variable `tasa`, y si su valor es nulo, osea, que devuelva un NULL o un empty string, hacemos que su valor sea 0 `if(!tasa){tasa = 0}`, el ! es la leche en programación, al menos como yo lo veo.
3. Hacemos un bucle for, al bucle debes darle una iteración, en este caso, i, con valor 2 (podría haber sido otro, pero me resultó mas fácil así) (`var i = 2`). Después, MIENTRAS que `i` sea MENOR O IGUAL A 10 (en este caso, 10 es la ruptura del bucle) (`i <= 10`) haz lo siguiente, i++ (añade +1 a `i`). Si aún no sabes usar bucles, aprende cuanto antes porque te ahorra mucho código a veces.
4. Ahora bien, lo que hay dentro del bucle for {...código entre llaves...} se va a ejecutar tantas veces como veces sume +1 `i`, por tanto, tenemos ya 8 valores distintos. Es la razón por la que se usa solo una variable para hacer el contenido `var val = i*10000` (*10000 multiplica por 10.000, para que de el resultado que querías). Así el valor va a ser 20.000 en el primer recorrido, ya que `i` por defecto vale 2, 2*10.000 = 20.000. `i` valdrá 3 en el segundo recorrido, por tanto 30.000, etc etc. Hasta que `i` valda 10, y por tanto, se rompa el bucle porque ya definimos como cierre del bucle `i <(menor)=(o igual a)10`
5. Luego solamente tenemos que dividir valor entre tasa, pasarlo por variable, y siguiendo en el mismo bucle, hacer que el texto de la columna, se cambie por conv. (Si te fijas, también uso `i-1`+der, eso es porque quiero seleccionar un #der cada vez que se itera, y como `i` por defecto es 2, tengo que restar 1 siempre. i-1).

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad se ve que que te tomaste el tiempo y te lo agradezco mucho, entiendo un poco tu explicacion(aunque hay demasiados conceptos que tengo que investigar), ahora bien, como añadiria esa funcion a mi codigo, es decir al que ya tengo, y si con esta funcion si me mostraria el calculo con los puntos, para que se entienda mejor el monto, que ese es mi problema principal, ya que me motraba en pantalla el calculo, solo que por ejemplo en lugar de devolver 1.500.000 devuelve 1500.000 faltando 1 punto para hacer mas entendible la sifra

Comment: Vale, para implementar la función, si te das cuenta, es la misma que la de tu código, borra la tuya y pon la mía, estaría ya implementada.
Ahora, entiendo que lo que quieres es poner los puntos de las cifras por miles, no= 1.000, 1.000.000.000.000?

Comment: Todo bien, pero ese **else** vacio no tiene sentido! @AQMR

Comment: const tasa = (document.querySelector("#tasa").value || 0)

Comment: function milis(n){
    if(!n) n = 0;

    return new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {minimumFractionDigits: 3}).format(n)
}

Complementa el codigo con esto, que transforma y formatea el numero sin necesidad de .toFixed(3).

Comment: document.getElementById(i-1+"der").innerHTML = milis(conv)